# What is the best practice to let guest user update record?

Tags: visualforce, guest-user

I have an apex controller trying to save changes to a record.  This has been traditionally done from a VisualForce page, but am getting

> System.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied for Name,
> controller action methods may not execute

Which I expect is due to the security changes imposed on the guest profile.  This is happening on a SOQL update call (`update custom_object__c`). The controller is defined without sharing.

```
public without sharing class nuController_Approval {

public Pagereference save() {
    if(temp.Status__c == 'Rejected' && temp.Rejection_Reason__c == null) {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,' Rejection Reason is required.'));
    }
    else if(temp.Approved_By__c == null || temp.Approved_By_Email__c == null) {
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,' Approved By and Appover\'s Email are required.'));
    }
    else {
        if(temp.Approved_On__c == null) {
            temp.Approved_On__c = Datetime.now();
            temp.Rejection_Reason__c = rejectionReason;
            temp.Approved_By__c = approvedBy;
            temp.Approved_By_Email__c = approverEmail;
        }
        temp.id = Tid;

        // V ERROR HAPPENS HERE V
        update temp;
        // ^^^^^^^^
        
        message = 'Your response has been saved. You may exit this window.';
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

What is the best practice for solving this without requiring the user to log in?  Can this be resolved by using LWC?

Requiring the creation of a user account, a community account just to update 3 fields seems a bit ridiculous, especially when the user updating the record may only do it once in the lifetime of the record.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/Guest-User-Record-Access-Development-Best-Practices

Comment: I would suggest you consider whether you can stop using guest access; Salesforce will continue to dumb this down over time for "better security" (and, in all probability, to drive more revenue through license sales).

Answer (score 0):

You say that the "controller is defined without sharing". Then it shouldn't matter for the Guest user if it has access or not.
Does the update action happen in the same controller class or in a different one (aka "helper") that may be "with sharing"? It would be helpful if you share the code.

Also, LWC or any other framework is just a UI. The main sharing / visibility functionality depends on the controller and all related classes and automations.

It's normal to have a Salesforce.com community / site / experience with a public page, which runs on behalf of the guest user. In my experience giving as minimum access as possible to a guest user's profile was the best approach.
Also, if you don't want to expose a "large" object like "Account" in a community, it's ok to  create a child custom object that would be accessible to a guest user on a public page and then act to capture requests. Then once a record is created in that object, you can build a custom trigger and code (without sharing) on the object to update any other "internal" objects (like Account) and records if needed.

Comment: Mike Var - added pertinent code snippet.